# Submitting to the Apple App Store. Developer account sign-up/renewal

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, app-store

I've created a phonegap application that I am ready to submit my free app to the apple app store.  But I first need to sign up for a developer ID.  I see that there is a $99 per year subscription fee.  My question is this.  If I submit my app now and it gets approved, will I need to renew my $99 fee next year for the app to stay available?  Or can I let my developer id expire?

Thank you.

Comment: This question is possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/a/4611300

Comment: Yes, No (filler to 15 character)

Comment: your apps won't be listed after your iOS Developer Program is expired, but they won't be deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not renew, your app will be removed from the store.  There will also be no way to pay you, if your app is not free.